# "Nested transaction are not supported" using pooling with MySQL Server >=5.7.17

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core

Starting - I guess - after reconfigured MySQL Server 5.7.17 from Developer Machine to Server Machine, our web app (.NET Core 1.2) stopped working. Whenever we try to start a transaction, MySQL throws an exception "Nested transaction are not supported." We use connection pooling, there is no transaction left in an open state when closing any connection. In fact, we used this with MySQL Server Community 5.7.17 and Connector 7.0.6-IR31 for over 2 years with no problems.

I reduced the problem to that even after a plain query the server status goes into "InTransaction". After closing this connection (goes back to connection pool) and reopening it right after and starting a transaction throws the exception.

Updating both servers to 5.7.21 and Connector to 8.0.10rc did not resolve the issue.

Using 5.5.57 (MariaDB) solves the issue, however, we don't like to downgrade our server due to this issue.

```
    public static IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var connection = new MySqlConnection(Settings.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }

    using (var dbConnection = GetConnection())
    {
        var list = dbConnection.Query("select * from cf_genre", null).ToList();
    }

    using (var dbConnection = GetConnection())
    {
         using (var transaction = dbConnection.BeginTransaction())
         {
              // Not reached! An exception is thrown: "Nested transactions are not supported."
         }
    }
```

Comment: Same problem using official MySql.Data 6.10.6. However, using .NET 4.6.1 with MySql.Data 6.10.6 fixes this issue! I have no idea, worst is, it used to work for 2 years...

Comment: Report the problem at https://bugs.mysql.com/report.php and try to get it verified.  You could also try [MySQL Connector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) as an alternative.